# Filtering observable array with knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Could you please find what I'm doing wrong with this array filter. Fiddle [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/9o4utk6t/)

I've been working on it, and making very slow progress. I checked on a lot of samples but not able to find my issue.

Thanks

```
 //This is the part I'm not able to fix
    self.filteredPlaces = ko.computed(function() {
      var filter = self.filter().toLowerCase();
      if (!filter) {
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.placeList(), function (item) {
        });
        return self.placeList();
      } else {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.placeList(), function(item) {
          var result = (item.city().toLowerCase().search(filter) >= 0);
          return result;
        });
      }
    });
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think I know what  you're trying to accomplish so I'll take a shot. There are a few things wrong with this code.

1. foreach in knockout accepts an array not a function.

   http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html
2. I think you're trying to hide entries that don't contain the text in the search box. For that you need the visible binding. I re-factored your code to the sample below.

   ```
   <div data-bind="foreach: placeList" class="alignTextCenter">
       <p href="#" class="whiteFont" data-bind="text: city, visible: isVisible"></p>
   </div>
   ```
3. I added isVisible as an item in your array, and an observable in your class.

   ```
   var initialPlaces = [
     {"city":"Real de Asientos","lat":22.2384759,"lng":-102.089015599999,isVisible:true},
     {"city":"Todos Santos","lat":23.4463619,"lng":-110.226510099999,isVisible:true},
     {"city":"Palizada","lat":18.2545777,"lng":-92.0914798999999,isVisible:true},
     {"city":"Parras de la Fuente","lat":25.4492883,"lng":-102.1747077,isVisible:true},
     {"city":"Comala","lat":19.3190634,"lng":-103.7549847,isVisible:true},
   ];

   var Place = function(data) {
     this.city = ko.observable(data.city);
     this.lat = ko.observable(data.lat);
     this.lng = ko.observable(data.lng);
     this.isVisible = ko.observable(data.isVisible);
   };
   ```

4. Lastly, you want to subscribe to the changes of "query" since it's on your text box so that the list updates when the text box changes. It's the self.query.subscribe line in my fiddle. I apologize about the formatting, I tried several times and could not get it to work.

[Working fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/jchaplin2/9o4utk6t/1/)

Comment: This solution makes unneeded changes and actually breaks things. Using a computed is a better approach than a mutation in a subscribe. Notice that when clearing the query, there's no way to get the original list back. Point 4 describes the **only** necessary fix, the other fixes are superfluous.

Answer (score 1):

You did not data-bind `filter` to any input. You used `query` instead.

Change your filter value to use the `query` observable:

```
var filter = self.query().toLowerCase();
```